# How to assign the value of selected date to a variable

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, variables, datetimepicker

This is my code

```
DateTimeFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    errorStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
    hintText: 'MM DD, YYYY',
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
    suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.event_note),
    labelText: 'Select Date',
  ),
  mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.date,
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
  validator: (e) =>
  (e?.day ?? 0) == 1
      ? 'Please not the first day'
      : null,
  onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
    // value = populdate;
  },
),
```

I want to put the selected date value into a variable. How to do that, tried many things but didn't get a solution.

Comment: please refer the packages that you use.  Im sure `DateTimeFormField` is not official material Widget. its from 3rd party API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you already set the value, but forget to update the state

```
  onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
    // value that you got on every changes happened
     populdate= value;
    
    print(populdate); // this should be printed an Instance of DateTime
    setState((){}); // update state, and rebuild the UI with latest value
  },
```

Comment: i tried doing this but this wont work.

Comment: what variable do you want to assign? @HimanshuBodwal

Comment: on the code above, we assign variable  populdate with new  selected `value`. 

do not inverted. see your code. it should be `popudate= value`  and NOT `value=populdate` , like your question code

Comment: its named populdate and its var. and yeah its same as `populdate=value`

Comment: have you correct in writing? and also try to print it. it should be non null

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
setState((){
populdate= value;
});},
```